# I'm developing a simple cross platform system tray application. Here are the requirements, which tools should I use?

Tags: c#, javascript, cross-platform, toolkit

I hope you can help!

In brief, what I need is something like a cross platform web browser, with little or no chrome, that is easily distributable and allows the (local and remote) HTML pages running in it to receive messages (JavaScript?) when system global hotkeys are pressed.

I'm developing a desktop application which will utilise an existing web-based REST API. I would like this app to be cross-platform (Windows, Mac OS and Linux) and have a consistent interface across all platforms. The app runs in the system tray and uses global hotkeys for convenient access to a lot of it's functions without having to open the main UI window.

I have already written a rough initial version of the app using C#/Windows Forms, but there are a few issues. It currently uses unmanaged Win32 code to provide support for global hotkeys, which is not cross-platform even if I ported it to Mono. Plus, it's really *not* very pretty...

Ideally, I'd like to build the UI using traditional web technologies like XHTML/CSS and use JavaScript/AJAX to communicate with the remote API, which is why I thought Adobe AIR would be a good solution—but unfortunately [it still doesn't support global hotkeys](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2009/10/everything_new_in_air_2.html). I've also looked at [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xulrunner) but I'm not sure I properly understand what that's intended for.

So the basic requirements for whichever combination of tools I will use are:

1. Allow me to create the user interface in XHTML/CSS/JavaScript
2. JavaScript to remotely communicate with the web API via AJAX
3. Allow the app to show—and be accessible via—a tray icon (in whatever OS it's running on)
4. Allow the app to respond to global hotkeys (again, in whatever OS it's running on)

Does anyone have any advice for me on this? I'm open to any suggestions and examples, no matter the language or tool.

**Edit:** I just stumbled across [Nokia's Qt Toolkit](http://qt.nokia.com/), does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think AIR application is a good solution. For the global hotkeys there are some "alternatives"  [Can I assign a global hotkey to an Adobe AIR app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153581/can-i-assign-a-global-hotkey-to-an-adobe-air-app)