# Do AIR applications support system wide hot keys or media keys?

Tags: air, keyboard-shortcuts

I know one of the features of AIR is it lives in a sandbox on the desktop, but can a AIR application hook to system wide hotkeys or the media keys (Play, Skip, etc.) on the keyboard? In other words, can an AIR application running on the desktop respond to keypresses even if the application does not have focus.

If so, how?

Comment: duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153581/can-i-assign-a-global-hotkey-to-an-adobe-air-app

Comment: Also vote for it in a non-hack way here: http://ideas.adobe.com/ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?c=9D564F43-979A-4E35-AA21-85A61B6AB8DE&idea_id=84DC322E-AB30-498E-B903-5919C6DDD91B

Comment: @shaunhusain Looks like a duplicate. Thanks!